# Where should I embed htmlspecialchars and why?

Tags: javascript, firebase, htmlspecialchars

I'm making a small chat app for my website. But now I'm not sure how and where to put the htmlspecialchars function in my code to prevent XSS when someone enters a chat message or username.

This bit of code manages the chat user-interface. The .render method gets the chat data from Firebase and renders it to the DOM so that it shows up in the chat window. I'm thinking this is when I should filter the output, but I'm not sure how.

JS:

```
class ChatUI {
  constructor(list) {
    this.list = list;

  }
  clear() {
    this.list.innerHTML = '';
  }
  render(data) {
    const when = dateFns.distanceInWordsToNow(
      data.created_at.toDate(),
      {
        addSuffix: true
      }
    );
    const html = `
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <span class="username">${data.username}</span>
      <span class="message">${data.message}</span>
      <div class="time">${when}</div>
    </li>
    `;
    this.list.innerHTML += html;
  }
}
```

And the HTML on the chat page:

```
<div id="chat" class="content active">
  <!-- new chat form  -->
    <form class="new-chat">
      <div class="input-group">
         <input type="text" id="message" class="form-control" required>
           <div class="input-group-append">
             <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Senden">
           </div>
       </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

If I'm all wrong and any other point in my code may work better, I can post that as well. But it's quite a lot, so I'm not adding it all for now. Would be great if anyone could help me with the syntax and/or explain to me what I should be doing instead.

EDIT:
DOM query for the provided html and according event listener that catches a user's chat message each time they hit enter:

```
const newChatForm = document.querySelector('.new-chat');

newChatForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const message = newChatForm.message.value.trim();
  chatroom.addChat(message)
    .then(() => newChatForm.reset())
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: That is not PHP, it's javascript and looks unrelated to the html you provided.

Comment: You're absolutely right, of course this is javascript. :') Don't know why I wrote PHP. I corrected it.

Comment: @Cinder Just delete this question. `htmlspecialchars()` is a PHP specific function for ensuring ampersands (&) are encoded correctly before being sent to the client. Unless you're trying to do something specific with JavaScript you need to take some time to figure out *what* you're asking and *how* you're approaching the problem. It would certainly help to understand what is client and what is server code too.

Answer (score 2):

i have used this code

```
class ChatUI {
constructor(list) {
    this.list = list;

}
clear() {
    this.list.innerHTML = '';
}
escapeHtml(message) {
    return message
        .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
        .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
        .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
        .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
        .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}
render(data) {



    const when = dateFns.distanceInWordsToNow(
        data.created_at.toDate(),
        {
            addSuffix: true
        }
    );
    const html = `
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <span class="username">${this.escapeHtml(data.username)}</span>
    <span class="message">${this.escapeHtml(data.message)}</span>
    <div class="time">${when}</div>
  </li>
  `;
    this.list.innerHTML += html;
}}
```

[image: here is the input that i have inserted in data.username and data.message]
[image: following output i got after running the code]